# How to force convert all my values from uint8 to int and not int64

Tags: python, numpy, encryption

I have a numpy `ndarray` of size `112 * 92`. This is basically a grayscale image read using`cv2.imread`. Since its grayscale so its maximum value is `255`.

I am trying to encrypt this array using the phe paillier library:  http://python-paillier.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#role-1

But I get an error when I run the `public_key.encrypt()` command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 1, in <listcomp>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/phe/paillier.py", line 169, in encrypt
    encoding = EncodedNumber.encode(self, value, precision)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/phe/encoding.py", line 176, in encode
    % type(scalar))
TypeError: Don't know the precision of type <class 'numpy.uint8'>.
```

Ive tried with `float` and `int64` and I keep getting the same error, except for the class change in the last line.

Whats strange is that if I run the example on their website where a list is manually entered, it works flawlessly. The only difference I can understand between my numpy array and their example is the type.

When checked in inspector their type is `int` whereas mine is `uint8`.

```
secret_number_list = [3.141592653, 300, -4.6e-12]
type(secret_number_list)
<class 'list'>
type(secret_number_list[1])
<class 'int'>
```

whereas if I do the same for my array I get:

```
type(image)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
type(image[0][0])
<class 'numpy.uint8'>
```

I tried converting this to `int` by using `image.astype(int)` but I got an `int64` type which gives the same error at encryption.

Is there a way to convert all values to `int` and not `int64`?

Comment: Have you tried calling `.tolist()` on your array? This should produce a list of ints.

Comment: Just try to convert your image from `np.int` to actual Python integers: `image=image.astype(object)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try list comprehension to produce a nested list of python *int*s then convert back to a numpy array:

```
import numpy
import cv2
from phe import paillier


openfilename = "/path/to/image.jpg"
img = cv2.imread(openfilename,0)

public_key, private_key = paillier.generate_paillier_keypair()

encrypted_number_list = [[public_key.encrypt(int(x)) for x in row] for row in img]
encrypted_number_array = numpy.array(encrypted_number_list)
print(encrypted_number_array)
```

This will be very slow for a large image

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I want. I'm very new to python, can you please comment what each line is doing, it would clear up a lot of this code for me. Also these two lines are for a single image. I have a list of lists of images. The folder and list structure has been explained in my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51387169/843036. Can you please suggest how to write a nested loop that loops over all images in that list and saves it in a new list of lists with the same structure of list of list representing folders per subject and each subject has 10 images. Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know (and you can see it in [the sources here](https://github.com/n1analytics/python-paillier/blob/0318db16086ada468265168d21167eb7c8216f9f/phe/encoding.py#L161)), you should pass only `int` or `float`. So you need to convert the `ndarray` to a nested list with `int` or `float` items. See [ndarray.tolist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html).

For example:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> b = a.tolist()
>>> type(a)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(b)
<class 'list'>
>>> type(a[0][0])
<class 'numpy.int64'>
>>> type(b[0][0])
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought.. so i cant use numpy anymore and am stuck with lists. Coming from matlab I was hoping to work with numpy. But I tried your suggestion and since I am working with images I cannot get the same thing back. ``new_ = image.tolist()`` and then ``back_ = np.array(new_)``. When I display using ``cv2.imshow(back_)`` its just a black window.

Comment: @StuckInPhD I think that converting ndarray items back to their initial type might help. `cv2.imshow(back_.astype(np.uint8))`.